# How can I used ReadAllLines with gzipped file

Tags: c#, gzip, file.readalllines

Is there a way to use the one-liner ReadAllLines on a gzipped file?

```
var pnDates = File.ReadAllLines("C:\myfile.gz");
```

Can I put GZipStream wrapper around the file some how?

Comment: I don't get it. Can you please explain better? Is your question how to read `GZipStream` line by line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `File.ReadAllLines()` treats the file specified as text file. A zipfile isn't that. It's trivial to do it yourself:

```
public IEnumerable<string> ReadAllZippedLines(string filename)
{
    using (var fileStream = File.OpenRead(filename))
    {
        using (var gzipStream = new GZipStream(fileStream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        {
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(gzipStream)) 
            {
                yield return reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not very familiar with yield. It appears to be doing an implicit  while((line=reader.ReadLine())=!null) { return line;}. Have I got the right idea?

Comment: See [yield (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9k7k7cf0.aspx). It causes the method to read and return one line at a time, instead of reading the entire file in memory at once.

Comment: Shouldn't the `yield return` be inside a loop to not just return the first line? maybe `while (!reader.EndOfStream)`

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing built-in. You'll have to write yourself a small utility function.

Comment: And then make a copy of ReadLines, not ReadAllLines.

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to inflate the file first as the algorithm for gzip deals with byte data not text and incorporates a CRC. This should work for you:
**EDIT** - I cant comment for some reason, so this if for the bytestocompress question

```
byte[] decompressedBytes = new byte[4096];
using (FileStream fileToDecompress = File.Open("C:\myfile.gz", FileMode.Open))
{
    using (GZipStream decompressionStream = new GZipStream(fileToDecompress, CompressionMode.Decompress))
    {
        decompressionStream.Read(decompressedBytes, 0, bytesToCompress.Length);
    }
}
var pnDates = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decompressedBytes);
```

Comment: And where does `bytesToCompress` come from?

Comment: Did you post this as an answer to the wrong question?